# Find variable Hex values from single int

Tags: sql-server

I imagine this might be trivial but I don't know the correct terminology to search for a solution. What I need is when selecting an int value from a table column, it represents a number of possible Hex values which I would read using Hex Signed 2's complement. I am not sure what to store the Hex value as but it seems varbinary would be the likely option.

Table A holds the Enum's

```sql
EnumName nvarchar(10)
EnumValue varbinary(10)
```

Sample Values

(Val1,0x00000001),(Val2,0x00000002),(Val5,0x00000010)

It follows the patter 1,2,4,8 before moving on to the next place.

So as an example a value in Table b is -2147483648, using an online converter I can see the 2's complement is 80000000 so I can see in the enum list that it is the last value 0x80000000 (Value 28 in the table). However, some can have multiple values such as -2147090430 is 80060002 so this is the enums 0x00000002 (Value 2) and 0x80000000 (Value 28).

In SQL server there may be a way to do this but as I say, I don't know exactly what I am asking to search.

If anyone wants to correct my terminology I would be grateful.

Comment: Why not use a `varbinary` if you want to store hex value?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo, I did mean varbinary as that was the consensus on Google.